# XKB: Shift or control + numpad = down without shift

Tags: xkb

I'd like to map my keyboard so that (when the Numlock is On), the numpad key `2` named `KP_2` procudes a 2, but when I press Shift or Control I want this same key to produce a `Down` event, exactly like the down key.

So I created a new type like that contains the following added lines:

```
    modifiers= Shift+Control+NumLock+LevelThree;
    map[Shift+NumLock]= Level1;
    preserve[Shift+NumLock]= None;
    ...
    map[Control+NumLock]= Level1;
    preserve[Control+NumLock]= None;
```

So the whole type becomes:

```
type "FOUR_LEVEL_MIXED_KEYPAD_CUST" {
    modifiers= Shift+Control+NumLock+LevelThree;
    map[Shift+NumLock]= Level1;
    preserve[Shift+NumLock]= None;
    map[NumLock]= Level2;
    map[Shift]= Level2;
    map[LevelThree]= Level3;
    map[NumLock+LevelThree]= Level3;
    map[Shift+LevelThree]= Level4;
    map[Shift+NumLock+LevelThree]= Level4;
    map[Control+NumLock]= Level1;
    preserve[Control+NumLock]= None;
    level_name[Level1]= "Base";
    level_name[Level2]= "Number";
    level_name[Level3]= "Alt Base";
    level_name[Level4]= "Shift Alt";
    };
```

And I changed the `KP_2` section to take this into account that way:

```
    key  <KP2> {
        type= "FOUR_LEVEL_MIXED_KEYPAD_CUST",
        symbols[Group1]= [         Down,            KP_2,           U2193,           U21D3 ]
    };
```

(see `KP_Down` became `Down` and I changed the name of the group)

Unfortunately, when I run `xkbcomp preserve_none.xkb $DISPLAY`, on LibreOffice Calc, `Shift + (NumLock) + KP2` produces something like a `Shift + Down` (it both goes down and select, despite the `preserve[...]=None`), and when I press `Ctrl + KP2`, basically nothing happen, I don't even move.

Do you see what I did wrong? Thanks!

NB: You can find the whole file here: http://paste.debian.net/1063341

Answer (score 1):

Hum, I think I found the solution using something based on this answer : https://superuser.com/questions/801611/how-to-make-all-applications-respect-my-modified-xkb-layout/1000320#1000320

So first, I don't know why, but it seems that for some reason I need to use `type[Group1]=...` instead of just `type=...` even if sometimes it works.

Then, the key was to introduce some new symcodes (not sure it's the good term) osfDown/osfUp/.... For example, here we say that the symcode `osfLeft` should be interpreted as a press on the key `<LEFT>`, after releasing the `Shift` key (at least it's how I understand it):

```
    interpret osfLeft {
        repeat= True;
        action = RedirectKey(keycode=<LEFT>, clearmodifiers=Shift);
    };
```

If instead you want to release the modifier `Control`, you can replace `Shift` with `Control`, or even `Control+Shift` if you want to clear both. Then, you need to replace the old `KP_Left` symcode with the symcode that we just created:

```
    key  <KP4> {
        type[Group1]= "FOUR_LEVEL_MIXED_KEYPAD",
        symbols[Group1]= [ osfLeft,            KP_4,           U2190,           U21D0 ]
    };
```

That way, instead of generating a KP_Left (and eventually the `Shift/Control` associated, depending on what you pressed), this will remove the `Shift/Control` modifier (again, depending on what you configured in `osfLeft`).

So at that step here is a first solution:

```
# Load with xkbcomp shift_numpad.xkb $DISPLAY
# List modifiers: xmodmap -pm
xkb_keymap {
    xkb_keycodes { 
        include "evdev+aliases(azerty)"
    };
    xkb_types { 
        include "complete"  
    };
    xkb_compat { 
        include "complete"
        interpret osfLeft {
            repeat True;
            action = RedirectKey(keycode=<LEFT>, clearmodifiers=Shift);
        };
        interpret osfRight {
            repeat= True;
            action = RedirectKey(keycode=<RGHT>, clearmodifiers=Shift);
        };
        interpret osfUp {
            repeat= True;
            action = RedirectKey(keycode=<UP>, clearmodifiers=Shift);
        };
        interpret osfDown {
            repeat= True;
            action = RedirectKey(keycode=<DOWN>, clearmodifiers=Shift);
        };
    };
    xkb_symbols { 
        include "pc+fr(oss)+fr(bepo):2+inet(evdev)+ctrl(swapcaps)"
        key  <KP8> {
            type= "FOUR_LEVEL_MIXED_KEYPAD",
            symbols[Group1]= [ osfUp,            KP_8,           U2191,           U21D1 ]
        };
        key  <KP4> {
            type= "FOUR_LEVEL_MIXED_KEYPAD",
            symbols[Group1]= [ osfLeft,            KP_4,           U2190,           U21D0 ]
        };
        key  <KP5> {
            type= "FOUR_LEVEL_MIXED_KEYPAD",
            symbols[Group1]= [ osfDown,            KP_5,           U2194,           U21D4 ]
        };
        key  <KP6> {
            type= "FOUR_LEVEL_MIXED_KEYPAD",
            symbols[Group1]= [ osfRight,            KP_6,           U2192,           U21D2 ]
        };
        key  <KP2> {
            type= "FOUR_LEVEL_MIXED_KEYPAD",
            symbols[Group1]= [ osfDown,            KP_2,           U2193,           U21D3 ]
        };

    };
    xkb_geometry { 
        include "pc(pc105)" 
    };
};
```

Note however that the type `"FOUR_LEVEL_MIXED_KEYPAD"` does not define anything for `Control`, and in my case I wanted to have `Shift+2` to be equivalent to `Shift+Down` (i.e. select), but also that `Control+2` generate a `Down` without any modifier. So I needed to update the definition of `osfLeft` in order to remove the modifier `Control`, but keep the modifier `Shift` if it was already present. Then, I needed to define an a custom type that maps also `Ctrl` on level 1:

```
    type "FOUR_LEVEL_MIXED_KEYPAD_CUST" {
        modifiers= Shift+NumLock+LevelThree+Control;
        map[Shift+NumLock]= Level1;
        map[Control+NumLock]= Level1;
        map[NumLock]= Level2;
        map[Shift]= Level2;
        map[Control]= Level2;
        map[LevelThree]= Level3;
        map[NumLock+LevelThree]= Level3;
        map[Shift+LevelThree]= Level4;
        map[Shift+NumLock+LevelThree]= Level4;
        level_name[Level1]= "Base";
        level_name[Level2]= "Number";
        level_name[Level3]= "Alt Base";
        level_name[Level4]= "Shift Alt";
    };
```

If I put that all together, it gives:

```
# Load with xkbcomp shift_numpad.xkb $DISPLAY
# List modifiers: xmodmap -pm
xkb_keymap {
    xkb_keycodes { 
        include "evdev+aliases(azerty)"
    };
    xkb_types { 
        include "complete"
        type "FOUR_LEVEL_MIXED_KEYPAD_CUST" {
            modifiers= Shift+NumLock+LevelThree+Control;
            map[Shift+NumLock]= Level1;
            map[Control+NumLock]= Level1;
            map[NumLock]= Level2;
            map[Shift]= Level2;
            map[Control]= Level2;
            map[LevelThree]= Level3;
            map[NumLock+LevelThree]= Level3;
            map[Shift+LevelThree]= Level4;
            map[Shift+NumLock+LevelThree]= Level4;
            level_name[Level1]= "Base";
            level_name[Level2]= "Number";
            level_name[Level3]= "Alt Base";
            level_name[Level4]= "Shift Alt";
        };
    };
    xkb_compat { 
        include "complete"
        interpret osfLeft {
            repeat= True;
            action = RedirectKey(keycode=<LEFT>, clearmodifiers=Control);
        };
        interpret osfRight {
            repeat= True;
            action = RedirectKey(keycode=<RGHT>, clearmodifiers=Control);
        };
        interpret osfUp {
            repeat= True;
            action = RedirectKey(keycode=<UP>, clearmodifiers=Control);
        };
        interpret osfDown {
            repeat= True;
            action = RedirectKey(keycode=<DOWN>, clearmodifiers=Control);
        };
    };
    xkb_symbols { 
        include "pc+fr(oss)+fr(bepo):2+inet(evdev)+ctrl(swapcaps)"
        key  <KP8> {
            type[Group1]= "FOUR_LEVEL_MIXED_KEYPAD_CUST",
            symbols[Group1]= [ osfUp,            KP_8,           U2191,           U21D1 ]
        };
        key  <KP4> {
            type[Group1]= "FOUR_LEVEL_MIXED_KEYPAD_CUST",
            symbols[Group1]= [ osfLeft,            KP_4,           U2190,           U21D0 ]
        };
        key  <KP5> {
            type[Group1]= "FOUR_LEVEL_MIXED_KEYPAD_CUST",
            symbols[Group1]= [ osfDown,            KP_5,           U2194,           U21D4 ]
        };
        key  <KP6> {
            type[Group1]= "FOUR_LEVEL_MIXED_KEYPAD_CUST",
            symbols[Group1]= [ osfRight,            KP_6,           U2192,           U21D2 ]
        };
        key  <KP2> {
            type[Group1]= "FOUR_LEVEL_MIXED_KEYPAD_CUST",
            symbols[Group1]= [ osfDown,            KP_2,           U2193,           U21D3 ]
        };

    };
    xkb_geometry { 
        include "pc(pc105)" 
    };
};
```

NB: And if you want to play with the Super/LWIN key, it's exactly the same thing, but use `Mod4` instead of `Shift`, and make sure you have a

```
            modifier_map Mod4 { <LWIN> };
```

in the symbol section!